# Server deployment error : cap dev deploy BRANCH_TO_DEPLOY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, rubygems

1.Hi all , please i need help!
2.i want to deploy a code on a dev server and when i put this command
cap dev deploy BRANCH_TO_DEPLOY this error appear 
what can i do ?

```
    *WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
  redis (>= 3.0)
  redis-namespace (>= 0)
  connection_pool (>= 1.0.0)
  json (>= 0)*emphasized text*
  i18n (~> 0.6)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
  Please report a bug if this causes problems.
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@global/gems/bundler-      1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already ``activated celluloid 0.14.1, but your Gemfile requires celluloid 0.12.4. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

3. when i use bundle exec this error appear

   ```
   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@global/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:256:in `block in replace_gem': capistrano is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `bundle exec`. Run `bundle update celluloid`, in order that the version of celluloid in your `Gemfile.lock` is the same as the latest celluloid gem that you've installed.

Comment: it doesn't work  You have already activated celluloid 0.14.1, but your Gemfile requires celluloid 0.12.4. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: "your Gemfile requires celluloid 0.12.4" means that in your `Gemfile.lock` there's a line that says "use celluloid 0.12.4". That's the cause of this problem. Either fix your Gemfile.lock, manually or via bundle update, or `gem uninstall celluloid` all the versions later than 0.12.4.